# ASP.NET Error in Maximizer CRM 12 Web Access

Tags: asp.net

I got the following error after I installed Maximizer CRM 12 (Web Access).

> "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. "

The Code is 100% correct and i would prefer not to touch it.

My system is Windows Server 2008 R2, Running IIS 7.5, ASP.Net 4.0 and MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Laurence

---

Full Error Details:

### Server Error in '/MaximizerWebAccess' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Maximizer.Employee.Content.MyWorkDay.mwdTasks.SetInterfaceStrings() in d:\v12\Release_v12\WebPortals\Employee\Content\MyWorkDay\mwdTasks.aspx.cs:36
   Maximizer.Employee.Content.MyWorkDay.mwdTasks.OnInit(EventArgs e) in d:\v12\Release_v12\WebPortals\Employee\Content\MyWorkDay\mwdTasks.aspx.cs:786
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +480

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error in proprietary commercial software where the source code is not available.

Comment: Saying that "The Code is 100% correct" is almost certainly false when discussing *any* software, but when you're talking about **Maximizer CRM** that statement is absolutely laughable.